# Fs.renameSync throws Error: ENOENT while renaming, but the file exists

Tags: node.js, fs

Why does fs.Renamesync throw an error here:

```
this.parentDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'Logs', serverType + '-logs');
this.logFilePath = path.resolve(this.parentDirectory, 'latest.log');
if (fs.existsSync(this.logFilePath)){
  var newName = await firstLine(this.logFilePath);
  newName += '.log';
  fs.renameSync(this.logFilePath, path.join(this.parentDirectory, newName));
}
```

it says this:

`(node:648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\Unity\Projects\FlipSide\Logs\room-logs\latest.log' -> 'D:\Unity\Projects\FlipSide\Logs\room-logs\Log-room-2020-08-14T22:58:20Z.log'`

(No this is not unity script, it is an independent node server.)

The file exists, but it won't rename.

Comment: Do all the directories on the _target_ path exist? ENOENT may be about them, not the source file.

Comment: @9000 Yes, it only renames if the file exists, it would throw an error at existsSync if all the directories didn't exist... right...?

Answer (score 1):

A proper answer, because examples don't fit into a comments.

I suspect that the *destination* directory does not exist, maybe several levels above it, too.

```sh
cd /tmp
mkdir -p a/b/c   # A few levels exist.
touch a/foo.bar  # Our source file definitely exists. 
node
# Welcome to Node.js v13.2.0.
```

Now in Node REPL:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
// The destination directory does not exist, many levels of it.
fs.renameSync('a/foo.bar', 'a/b/c/d/e/f/g/foo.bar')
Thrown:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'a/foo.bar' -> 'a/b/c/d/e/f/g/foo.bar'
    at Object.renameSync (fs.js:659:3) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'rename',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'a/foo.bar',
  dest: 'a/b/c/d/e/f/g/foo.bar'
}
```

No, the exception message never specifies whether it was the source or the destination.

Comment: Well, it is moving within the same directory. And since the file exists, obviously the directory exists.